# Invoking nested functions in the Dart programming language

Tags: dart

I defined an inner function here:

```
person(firstName, lastName){
    fullName(){ //Is it possible to invoke this function outside the 'person' function?
        return firstName + " "  + lastName;
    }
    firstInitial(){
        return firstName[0];
    }
    lastInitial(){
        return lastName[0];
    }
}
```

Next, I tried to invoke the "fullName" function from the "main" function:

```
void main() {
  print(person("Rob", "Rock").fullName());
}
```

but it produced this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullName$0' of undefined
```

Is it possible to invoke an inner function outside the scope where the function is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare the function outside the enclosing block:

```dart
void main() {
  var fullName;
  person(firstName, lastName){
      fullName = () => "firstName: $firstName lastName: $lastName";
  }
  person("Rob", "Rock");
  print(fullName());
}
```

or return it:

```dart
void main() {
  person(firstName, lastName) => () => "firstName: $firstName"
                                       "lastName: $lastName";
  print(person("Rob", "Rock")());
}
```

If you want this syntax `person("Rob", "Rock").fullName()` you can return class instance:

```dart
class Res{
  var _firstName, _lastName;
  Res(this._firstName, this._lastName);
  fullName() => "firstName: $_firstName lastName: $_lastName";
}
void main() {
  person(firstName, lastName) => new  Res(firstName,lastName);
  print(person("Rob", "Rock").fullName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those functions can be invoked externally, the issue is that your program can't see them. Your function returns void, so the inner functions are invisible.

But what it looks like you're trying to do is define a class. So a simpler way to do it is

```
  class Person {
    var firstName, lastName;
    Person(this.firstName, this.lastName);
    get fullName => "$firstName $lastName";
    firstInitial() => firstName[0];
    lastInitial() { return lastName[0]; }
  }

  main() {
    print(new Person("Rob", "Rock).fullName);
    print(new Person("Robert", "Stone").lastInitial());
  }
```

For illustration I used three different syntaxes for the three different functions, a getter, a lambda, and a full-blown function.